# Fullcalendar - How to customize dayMaxEventRows for indivisual date

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I want to set a full calendar dayMaxEventRows number for individual dates. But I dint find any option for that.

Set dayMaxEventRows different numbers for individual dates. So that I can manage more links and max event count.

I want to set dayMaxEventRows date-wise. like 02.11.2022 wnat set dayMaxEventRows to 2 and 09.11.2022 set dayMaxEventRows to 3. Please suggest how to achieve this functionality.

[image]

Comment: There is no way to do that currently? But why would you want to? You don't know in advance how many events will be on that day.

Comment: You can see the image ... I want that where Unavailable text is present want to set the max event to 2.

Comment: Yes you already said that. That wasn't my question. My question was _why_ you'd want do to it, given that when you are configuring this you cannot predict how many events will be actually be present. By what logic would you define the numbers to be shown on each day? But also I've also already explained that there is no feature for this. Perhaps you can make a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) to the makers of fullCalendar.